# Should I decline a gift from a recruiter?

Tags: recruitment

I was recently offered a job by a recruiter (company HR). After a couple of calls, I declined the offer.

Today I got a new mail:

> Hey [X]
>
> Hope you're having a good time. I just wanted to send across a book to you, was wondering what address can i send it at?
> Could you please email me the address.

I am not sure what the correct response to this should be. Is it okay to accept it? If not, how should I politely decline it?

Comment: He's phishing for information to sell.  Sounds like a scam to me.

Comment: Does your company not have a policy covering gifts? If it does I would refer to that. I believe my last company had a policy that it was OK to accept a gift with a value less than £20, any more than that and you should discuss it with a line manager if possible or decline it.

Comment: @Jack Alternatively, it could be material designed to change the OP's mind re. the job offer, or to sell the company in some way to someone else. Agreed that it's unlikely to be purely altruistic.

Comment: If it wouldn't be inconvenient to you, and you're worried about him phishing for your address, you could offer to pick it up directly

Comment: Tell him/her that they can bring the book next time they treat you to lunch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The recruiter may just want to stay on your good side. Small gifts to business contacts are pretty common. I have sent and received business books to people outside my organization, just to be friendly. (Yes, that does happen.) I don't see any downside to accepting.

[Jack](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/47546/should-i-decline-a-gift-from-a-recruiter#comment119915_47546) is concerned that the recruiter may be phishing for information. I don't see this as an issue here, because selling snail mail addresses is probably not worth anyone's time if they already have your email address. Plus, you mention that he is from an HR department, not a freelancer, so I'd discount the phishing hypothesis even further.

[Dustybin80](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/47546/should-i-decline-a-gift-from-a-recruiter#comment119917_47546) brings up your company's policy on gifts. I don't think this is pertinent. because you are in touch with the recruiter as a private individual, not as an employee of your company.